# Convert a mixed string to UTF16 with PHP

Tags: unicode, encoding

I have a string in PHP like this:

> INPUT = "Γιώργο αν στείλεις αυτό ακριβώς (:

Its a mixed string with GREEK and LATIN characters at the same time. I want all characters in a given string to be converted to this string

> OUTPUT = 0022039303B903CE03C103B303BF002003B103BD002003C303C403B503AF03BB03B503B903C2002003B103C503C403CC002003B103BA03C103B903B203CE03C200200028003A

How can I convert the input to this kind of output?

Comment: 1) mb_convert_encoding() *is* a valid solution. 2) Convert from what encoding?

Comment: UTF-8 to utf-16. And I can't understand why you downgraded the question. Sure mb_convert is a valid solution but doesn't work in my case. So its not a solution for me.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. The downvoter didn't leave a comment.

Comment: Ah alright. I am sorry :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out but it seems that what you want to do is to convert a UTF-8 string to an uppercase binary dump of its UTF-16 representation. It's as simple as this:

```
$input = '"Γιώργο αν στείλεις αυτό ακριβώς (:';
$output = mb_strtoupper(bin2hex(mb_convert_encoding($input, 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8')));
```

The `BE` suffix indicates Big Endian, which seems to be the expected byte order according to your example.

Comment: +1 but it's probably easiest just to use `UTF-16BE` instead of worrying about endianess

Comment: @Esailija - Thanks for the tip, I've incorporated it to the answer. I was not aware of it.

Comment: Thank you Alvaro. That was perfect. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried iconv?  Maybe something like this:
(EDIT) i understand your main goal is to be able this converted string to be transported via http to your service, in that case you can use **base64_encode()** on the result.
see the complete code example:

```
<?php
    $string = str_replace(' ', '', "Γιώργο αν στείλεις αυτό ακριβώς");
    $converted = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', $string);
    $encoded = base64_encode($converted);

    var_dump($encoded);
    var_dump(iconv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', base64_decode($encoded)));
?>
```

You will get:

**encoded:** string '/v8DkwO5A84DwQOzA78DsQO9A8MDxAO1A68DuwO1A7kDwgOxA8UDxAPMA7EDugPBA7kDsgPOA8I=' (length=76)
**decoded:** string 'Γιώργοανστείλειςαυτόακριβώς' (length=54)

Comment: string '���������������������������������' (length=60). This is what I get. Also the string should be mixed ( English + Greek Chars).

Comment: @GeorgeD. Whatever you see in the browser is irrelevant unless you tell it to display as UTF-16.

Comment: When I display as UTF-16 I get this-> 㰡䑏䍔奐䔠䡔䵌㸍਼桴浬⁬慮朽≥渭啓∾ഊ㱨敡搾ഊ††㱭整愠捨慲獥琽≕呆ⴸ∾ഊ††㱴楴汥㸼⽴楴汥㸍਼⽨敡搾ഊ㱢潤社ഊ††㱰牥⁣污獳㴧硤敢畧⵶慲ⵤ畭瀧⁤楲㴧汴爧㸼獭慬氾獴物湧㰯獭慬氾‼景湴⁣潬潲㴧⍣挰〰〧㸧Γιώργο☣〻αν☣〻στείλεις☣〻αυτό☣〻ακριβώς✼⽦潮琾‼椾⡬敮杴栽㘰⤼⽩㸊㰯灲放㰯扯摹㸍਼⽨瑭氾

Comment: This is faw away from something like 0022039303B903CE03C103B303BF002003B103BD002003C303C403B503AF03BB03B503B903C2002003B103C503C403CC002003B103BA03C103B903B203CE03C200200028003A

Comment: hello , well i guess you can always use 'base64_encode()'

Comment: i edited my answer for convenience with new complete code example

Comment: Thank you Vlad. I tested it with the example string and I got this return string '/V8AIGOTA7KDZGPBA7MDVWOXA70DWWPEA7UDRWO7A7UDUQPCA7EDXQPEA8WDSQO6A8EDUQOYA84DWGAOADO=' (length=84) that is again not then one I want